# How to add CVS extracare loyalty card to IOS wallet app?

Tags: ios, wallet

How does one add the [CVS loyalty card](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250983089) to the Wallet app?  Procedure in said link does not work. Although [PassSource](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/295128/how-do-i-add-loyalty-cards-to-the-ios-wallet) seems to be a solution, I would prefer to keep this data in the Wallet app.

Comment: You might want to consider using the [CVS Mobile app](https://www.cvs.com/mobile-cvs/apps) instead of Wallet. There doesn't seem to be any way to scan your CVS card.